# GET data lost when submit button

Tags: php, parameters, get

I have set a url like this in my signup

`https://www.example.com/signup?ref_token=5c4d9bc6d3cb2`

And my button should be like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Some code at here
}
```

Before the isset post I am still able to get the `$_GET['ref_token']` data but right after the post, the get data lost.

Comment: Could you add to your question your form please?

Comment: Usually you would use either GET or POST. If you have a form you could include the ref_token as a hidden input.

Comment: Check your action-attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to keep already set get parameter values on Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201124/how-to-keep-already-set-get-parameter-values-on-form-submission)

Comment: Yes I have a form for submission and thank you all that I'm able to get the data now by putting the value as hidden in an input control.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for you to transmit your form dats via post to the same url.

You can achieve this by using as form action target:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'?'.http_build_query($_GET); ?>
```

Another possibility would be to transmit your current GET parameters in a hidden field and evaluate them.